# Dock recommendation for Macbook Thunderbolt2 and Dell Thunderbolt 3 laptops

Tags: hdmi, thunderbolt, docking-stations

I'm looking for a dock that will allow my gf and I to connect 2 HDMI monitors and 2 USB mouse/keyboard devices to both a Macbook Air (2015) with thunderbolt 2 and a modern dell laptop with thunderbolt 3. The laptops would not be connected at the same time, I just want the capability to dock either one. Also charging capability for the laptop would be ideal, although I'm aware this probably might not be possible with the macbook over thunderbolt 2 -> 3 conversion.

My thought was to buy a dock that supports tb3, for the dell and then use a tb2 -> tb3 adapter to connect the macbook to the dock.

Something like this:

Macbook (TB 2) ---> Converter (tb2 -> tb3) -----> TB3 Dock

AND:

Dell TB3 (TB3) ----> TB3 Dock

- [https://www.amazon.com/DisplayPort-MacBook-Surface-Devices-Bi-Direction/dp/B07ZD3B89T/ref=asc_df_B07ZD3B89T/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07ZD3B89T)
- [https://www.amazon.com/TOTU-Display-Docking-Charging-Thunderbolt/dp/B07Z53139N/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07Z53139N)

Would this even work? What would be our cheapest option here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [adapter you linked](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07ZD3B89T) is not bi-directional, and may not work for your application. [This adapter](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207266) is bi-directional and should work for your application. *Note: This adapter does not allow power pass-through, so you will need to have the dock or dongle connected to its own power for this to work.*

The [dock you linked](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07Z53139N) is a good choice. I think it will work well for you. Because you asked for a cheaper option, you can use a "dongle" with power passthrough instead of a "dock." [Here is one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07X8V3SLM) that has the ports you asked for.

Comment: Thanks! I had seen the apple adaptor but my concern was that I'd need another cable TB2 Male to TB2 Male to connect my laptop to the adapter linked. Am I correct on this?

Comment: Yes, you will need a male-male cable to go between the adapter and Mac.

Comment: Okay cool. Thank you. So the chain would look like this:
Macbook -> MiniDisplayport cable -> Thunderbolt 2 Adapter -> Hub

Comment: On a related note, Thunderbolt 3 is backward-compatible with Thunderbolt 2, isn't it? So no adapter would be needed.

Comment: They have different plugs. The protocols have some compatibility, but you need an adapter.